# nogui not working on agrarian skies 3.1.1 SERVER

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-java-edition-server

Just as the title says, the `nogui` option is not working when I launch the .jar with that parameter. When I use the parameter, it just ignores it and launches the server GUI regardless if I execute the `.sh` in a terminal session or not.

I run the server using a `.sh` file containing the following:

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx5120m -XX:PermSize=128m -jar FTBServer-1.6.4-965.jar nogui
pause
```

This is Java version that I get when I type: `java -version`

```
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

I run the server on a net install of Debian I installed last week.

Debian version is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.5 (wheezy)
Release:    7.5
Codename:   wheezy
```

The debian machine is home made (not rented) and has a GUI. This is the first server I have run on this machine, so its not an issue that suddenly arose on this machine.

If I have not provided enough information, leave a comment and I'll try to get the information needed.

Comment: This question is off-topic both as tech support for modded minecraft and as a problem that isn't actually game-specific.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because tech support for modded Minecraft is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same porblem. The command worked from the shell directly, but not in the supplied script.

The supplied script is saved in a Microsoft format with the CRLF (or ^M) end-of-line marker, as opposed to the Unix LF only format, and thus the 'nogui' becomes 'nogui^M' which of course is an invalid argument and java / the server jar ignores it.

Unfortunately, most Linux distros use shells and editors which display these files as if they didn't have the CRLF in them, and you don't see it. Even after editing the file with a Linux editor, it can get saved with the ^M's still there.

If you can process the file with dos2unix or similar, the script should work.

Alternatively, you can downlaod my fixed script, which also clears up the 'pause' line (which only works in Windows) here: http://www.xorotude.com/mc/serverstart.html

tifkat

Comment: Thanks, the dos2unix fixed it.
Note to unix noobs like me:
  You need to install the package using: `sudo apt-get install dos2unix`

Answer (score 0):

Try and run it straight from a terminal session and see if that works, if it does then its the .sh file. just run this.

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar FTBServer-1.6.4-965.jar nogui
```

If that doesn't work, you have an issue with the server itself and I would say try with a vanilla server to see if it yields the same result.

Comment: thanks for the edit but i still prefer the sound of "Wields" makes it sound more epic